# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e when try to parse a JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I try to use JSON.parse to return a javascript object of the string below. However, I receive "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e" .

```
{
    "__type": "HRIS.oHRData, HRIES, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "TPDDListValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([]),
    "DPDDListValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([]),
    "TopDataValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([
        new Ajax.Web.DataTable([
            ["HID","System.String"],
            ["HFrName0","System.String"],
            ["HFtName0","System.String"],
            ["HGFName0","System.String"],
            ["HFmName0","System.String"],
            ["TID","System.Byte"]
        ],[
            ["123456789","ABCD1","ABCD2","ABCD3 ","ABCD4",2]
        ])
    ]),
    "DownDataValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([]),
    "MenuDataValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([]),
    "SearchReturnValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([]),
    "Result": null,
    "NewID": "NoID",
    "AffectedRecords": 0
}
```

I use this code:

```
var text= 'the json string here';

var obj=JSON.parse(text);
```

I think the issue is that JSON doesn't recognize the type of 
new Ajax.Web.DataSet([])

How can I solve this issue, please?

Any idea is appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Where does it come from? What is the context; why do you need to parse it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It is completely correct json format. the issue is related to new Ajax.Web.DataSet([]) which isn't recognizable by JSON.

Comment: it is most certainly **not** correct JSON format. There is no `new` keyword in JSON syntax. [Here is the reference](http://json.org/); check for yourself. JSON is a data interchange format that has no execution semantics at all; `new` just makes no sense.

Comment: That **is** correct JavaScript object initializer syntax, of course, but while JSON is clearly based on that, it's different. And generally you don't use `JSON.parse()` on JavaScript object initializers, because they're a superset of JSON syntax so you'll have exactly the problem you're having. Again, if you explain the context, somebody may be able to help.

Comment: If you need to check your JSON you can use http://jsonlint.com/. Also probably not the best idea to stubbornly contradict someone who is trying to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation,
I need to pass this java script object  initializer syntax from the server to the client through the json string.
So, I ask this question might someone had an experience in this issue.
Thank you again

Comment: It's not a JSON string :)

Comment: Thank you Craicerjack, you are right. It is a mistake. And I happy to say I am sorry mr Pointy.

Comment: It's not a JSON string.
What do you mean? If you mean 
new Ajax.Web.DataSet([])
You are right 
And my question how can I solve this issue? I try to pass it as a string but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really just dropping that into your code, you don't need quotes and you don't need to parse it:

```
var theObject = {
    "__type": "HRIS.oHRData, HRIES, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "TPDDListValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([]),
    "DPDDListValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([]),
    "TopDataValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([
        new Ajax.Web.DataTable([
            ["HID","System.String"],
            ["HFrName0","System.String"],
            ["HFtName0","System.String"],
            ["HGFName0","System.String"],
            ["HFmName0","System.String"],
            ["TID","System.Byte"]
        ],[
            ["123456789","ABCD1","ABCD2","ABCD3 ","ABCD4",2]
        ])
    ]),
    "DownDataValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([]),
    "MenuDataValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([]),
    "SearchReturnValue": new Ajax.Web.DataSet([]),
    "Result": null,
    "NewID": "NoID",
    "AffectedRecords": 0
};
```

This will require that whatever service provides that `Ajax` object exists.